# how to create index page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new to magento. I have installed magento in localhost and login admin panel.

Now i run `127.0.0.1/magento/admin` in localhost, after logged in it displayed one page it contains number of fileds such as cmc,catalog,...

May i know how to create and design home page in magento.

I refered in google, little i confused.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U might have not setup your magento properly, so refer to this below links & also install magento sample data

`http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf`
`http://www.magentocommerce.com/resources/user-guide-download`
`http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce`

After that simply access your magento http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/

Comment: :may i know what is the purpose of download sample data?

Comment: it will load some sample products & other functionality, by which you can easily understand frontend & backend of magento

Comment: @pandav: as you told, download again magento1.7 version in their official website, after complete download, in .zip didn't open, it will shows error.. what to do?..

Comment: can you help me out please?

Comment: which platform you are using linux or windows..?
and download ver 1.8.1.0 - .zip for windows/ ver 1.8.1.0 - .tar.gz for linux

Comment: @ S.Pandav: why that difference?

Comment: @S.Pandav: I have downloaded magento 1.8.0.1 and extract in magento folder. and downloaded sample data from this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-sample-data-archive-for-magento-ce. now what to do sample data?

Comment: First go through the above links before installing and getting messed up.. Magento is not just a software to install and play as you think. Go through the official documentation which can be helpful for u..

Answer (score 1):

There's a default home page installed on Magento. Go to backend: `CMS -> Pages` and select Home Page. There you can add content and markup. You can style your homepage with css, or use a custom layout.

This is the page `127.0.0.1/magento`.

Your shop doesn't have products, menu, etc. on homepage because you have a basic installation without sample data (products, categories, etc.). But you can add your own data.

You can add content in the `content` tab of the CMS `Home Page` page.

In `layout` tab, you can set page structure (3 columns, 2 columns right, etc) and change layout and add functionality via xml update.

For example, at the top of `layout` tab in `layout update xml` you can see:

```
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
    <action method="addPriceBlockType">
        <type>bundle</type>
        <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
        <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
    </action>
</block>
```

This snippet places the last added product to the homepage. So if you add a new product to the shop (`Catalog -> Manage Products -> New Product`), they will show up on the homepage.

A menu will show up if you add subcategories (`Catalog -> Manage Categories`) to Default Category, and set `active` and `include in navigation menu` to yes.

A slider or other modifications can also be added the same way via xml update or html-like in `content` tab.

If you are new to Magento, do some research on the web on magento layout and templating.

Comment: already i did, now it look like this http://imgur.com/fbCNHYb  .its just for sample, i didn't really do it. just i tried. but i want like in index page there is header in that have menus and next slide show and next products and footer.. etc. may i know how to do that?

Comment: Edited my answer.